# Css can´t find tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a problem with tailwind. When I install tailwind css always cant find tailwind.[Here is a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O86eR.png) I followed the tutorial on the Website and started a new project but every time I paste the css-code it shows an error. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Does tailwind work in your project? I have this warning aswell and it works with no problem. Its a warning by the way

Comment: This may be a warning on IDE. Please install tailwind related plugins in VS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to confirm the followings:

**1. Check if tailwind actually works.**

Please try to apply the following code as an example.

```
<div className="text-3xl font-bold">Example Title</div>
```

If you see the correct style, then your configuration is fine and there is no problem at all. So you need to check IDE.

Otherwise, you need to confirm the version of Tailwind you installed and its tailwind.config.js.

**2. IDE doesn't recognize the tailwind.**

Please try to install plugins related to tailwind in VS Code.